# NodeJS some mixing in module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning NodeJS and i have a little problem. Generally i would like to create site where you can login by giving your steam login, password and than steam token. I'm using steam-user npm module, and after i pass login+password there is required to give token by console input, but i would like to somehow pass it by browser. I have found inside module this code

```
    SteamUser.prototype._steamGuardPrompt = function(domain, lastCodeWrong, callback) {
if (this.options.promptSteamGuardCode) {
    var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
        "input": process.stdin,
        "output": process.stdout
    });

    rl.question('Steam Guard' + (!domain ? ' App' : '') + ' Code: ', function(code) {
        rl.close();
        callback(code);
    });
} else {
    this.emit('steamGuard', domain, callback, lastCodeWrong);
}
};
```

Can someone tell me how to modify it?

Comment: verify whether u have a token value in "callback(code)" ... if yes, u could add a 'token' parm to your app's routes and pass it around to indicate that user has a steam.token.value

Comment: token value is in "code, i think callback is a function to send this code to another function which check if token is correct. But i dont really understand how should i pass it

Comment: +i would be awesome if shows up this r1 question, some pop up connected to express.js will appear